# How to use setMessageReaction(node-telegram-bot-api)?

Tags: bots, telegram, node-telegram-bot-api

Getting error ETELEGRAM:

```
400 Bad Request: message to react not found
```

I am using the node-telegram-bot API and trying to set a reaction to a message in the channel via the `setMessageReaction` method:

```
bot.setMessageReaction method('@channel_name', message_id, [
{type: 'emoji', emoji: '' },
])
```

But I get the following error:

```
ETELEGRAM: 400 Bad Request: message to react not found
```

What could be the reason if the message id is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't the permissions, but the emoji needs to be passed this way.

```
const reaction = [{ type: 'emoji', emoji: '' }];

bot.setMessageReaction(chatId, messageId, {reaction: JSON.stringify(reaction)})
```

Comment: and how can we set the count of reaction?

Comment: but Aariyan right too, bot needs the permissions

Comment: Permissions are the same for bots and users. Moreover, there is no special permission to use reactions, they can be disabled only by completely disabling them in chat or channel.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to specify the number of reactions under one message. One user puts one reaction, and a bot is also a user. Of course there are still premium users who can have three reactions, but bots are currently not allowed to have premium. Promises to be made in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your bot needs to have the necessary permissions to add reactions in the target chat.

```
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');

const token = 'YOUR_BOT_TOKEN';
const bot = new TelegramBot(token, { polling: true });

const chatId = 123456789;
const messageId = 123; 

const reaction = [{ type: 'emoji', emoji: '' }]; 

bot.setMessageReaction(chatId, messageId, reaction)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Reaction added successfully!');
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error adding reaction:', error);
  });
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. there doesn't seem to be anything in the documentation about the necessary permissions. therefore, I thought that you can set the reaction in any open channel where reactions are available.
how do I add the necessary permissions to the bot?

Comment: you typically need to add the bot as an administrator to the channel. This is because most interactions with channel content, beyond basic reading, require administrative privileges.

Comment: Yes, it works that way, thank you! the result returns true, but the emoji was not displayed on the post itself.
it would be more interesting if it were possible to put reactions on any channels :)